# Por que meu select não retorna no PHP?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, select

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Tenho uma consulta PHP que é a seguinte:

```
<?php
$serverName = "servidor";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"banco", "UID"=>"user", "PWD"=>"senha");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo );
if( $conn === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$sql = "SELECT  distinct  CONVERT(date, colunadata,103)as data FROM LISTA2 WHERE colunadata IS NOT NULL and DESCRICAO like '%valor%' GROUP BY CONVERT(date,colunadata,103)";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
     $dateString = $row['data']->format('d/m');
      echo $dateString."<br />";
}

sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);

?>
```

Acontece que dependendo do valor que coloco na WHERE ele funciona e printa na tela o resultado conforme o "ECHO" definido acima. No entanto coloquei este select dentro de uma query no SQL SERVER e retorna valor! Por que nao retorna alguns valores no PHP ?

Comment: Coloca a consulta feita no SQL SERVER na pergunta

Comment: É o mesmo select que mostrado dentro da variável $sql

Comment: @LeonardoBarros você tem alguma ideia do porquê nao esta funcionando?

Comment: O SQL Profile está mostrando exatamente o que deve ser executado?

Comment: sim @Onaiggac, está mostrando exatamente o que deve ser executado. Vou editar a pergunta postando a query no sql server

Comment: a query no sql server roda e retorna o valor corretamente mas quando coloco a mesma query no PHP ele não retorna valor algum, a tela fica branca simplesmente

Comment: Está diferente, um tem `DESCRICAO` o outro `GRUPO_DESCRICAO `

Comment: ah sim é tudo GRUPO_DESCRICAO, foi erro meu ao postar @LeonardoBarros

Comment: Como você atribui o valor do like?

Comment: o select seria "SELECT  distinct  CONVERT(date, colunadata,103)as data FROM LISTA2 WHERE colunadata IS NOT NULL and GRUPO_DESCRICAO 
like '%209524 | *2.8* GR. ROLO FIBRA DE CARBONO Ø146%' GROUP BY CONVERT(date,colunadata,103)". O valor na verdade é essa string

Comment: Não tem muito sentido este DISTINCT se você faz um GROUP BY pelo mesmo campo.

Comment: @anonimo sim... mesmo tirando o GROUP BY o retorno é o mesmo! E na query no sql server funciona como pode ser visto na imagem

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93147/380740-por-que-meu-select-nao-retorna-no-php)

Comment: "dependendo do valor que coloco na WHERE ele funciona e printa na tela o resultado". Por acaso essas vezes que funciona tem alguma relação com os as datas cujos DIAS são inferiores a 13?

Comment: Não... @RonaldoAraújoAlves. Tem vezes que retornam com dias 21,02,14, 27..varia.

Comment: @RonaldoAraújoAlves pq a ideia dias inferiores a 13 ?

Comment: Pra caso a data seja, por exemplo, 20/06/2019 e o sistema esteja tentando converter o "20" como mês.